# rucaptcha не работает

Tags: recaptcha

Пройдясь по всем шагам в документации rucaptcha попытался автоматически разгадать капчу https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo. Вышла ошибка zero_filesize, причём был включен sandbox режим, а деньги всё равно списались. Не могу написать проект заказчику из-за таких багов, а время идёт, надеюсь на вашу помощь, бывало ли когда-нибудь у вас такое?

P.S Поддержка сможет ответить только через 12 часов, у меня нет столько времени

Answer (score 0):

Жаль, мы только сейчас увидели Ваше сообщение. Лучше, конечно, писать в поддержку.

У нас есть два метода решения рекапчи: картинками и токеном.
zero_filesize - такая ошибка могла выйти только, если Вы решали рекапчу путём отправки картинки нам. Но намного проще решать капчу токеном.

https://rucaptcha.com/api-rucaptcha#solving_recaptchav2_new

Если вы именно этим путём и шли и при этом получали ошибку zero_filesize, значит Вы некорректно формировали запрос на загрузку капчи и не передали параметр
method=userrecaptch

Comment: В итоге оказалось, что капча на странице есть, но можно зарегистрироваться не вводя её, т.е на сайте была кривая капча, видимо из-за этого api выдавал ошибку ;D